# Accessing a dictionary contained as a string inside a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

The data looks like this

```
dc = {'statusID': 210,
 'employee': '{"result": [{"name": "Tom", "Salary": "$4530"}]}'}
```

I would like to access the employee name "Tom"

Here is what I tried

```
for key in dc.items():
    for values in key:
        print(values.result)
```

It gives me an error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'result'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the string:

```py
from ast import literal_eval


dc = {
    "statusID": 210,
    "employee": '{"result": [{"name": "Tom", "Salary": "$4530"}]}',
}

emp = literal_eval(dc["employee"])
print(emp["result"][0]["name"])
```

Prints:

```
Tom
```

Comment: Aha, so I was searching with the wrong keywords. Thanks for your answer